# Is the pairwise independence gap bounded to $\left[-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right]$? What about for n variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, independence, probability-inequalities, bounds

The [independence gap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association/589235#589235) is defined as

$$\phi_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \triangleq F_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) - \prod_{j=1}^n F_{X_j}(x_j)$$

where $F_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is the joint CDF over random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and $F_{X_j}(x_j)$ is the marginal CDF over the random variable $X_j$.

When I first considered this function I figured that the image would be $[-1,1]$ from plugging in the min/max values in $[0,1]$ for the respective joint and marginal probabilities.

$$\underbrace{1}_{\text{joint}} - \underbrace{0}_{\text{marginals}} = \underbrace{1}_{\text{independence gap}}$$
$$\underbrace{0}_{\text{joint}} - \underbrace{1}_{\text{marginals}} = \underbrace{-1}_{\text{independence gap}}$$

But then I started considering the [Frechet inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities). If I started with the marginals only, I could put an interval on the possible values of the joint probability without any assumption of statistical independence. And then compute an interval for independence gap using basic [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

What I found was that for pairs of variables that the independence gaps were more tightly bounded than I had expected from the above calculations. Intead of $\phi_{X_1, X_2} \in [-1,1]$ I found that $\phi_{X_1, X_2} \in \left[ -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right]$. From what I understand the Frechet inequalities don't make any special assumptions, but I could be wrong.

Is my inference correct that the pairwise independence gap is bounded to $\left[-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right]$?

> **Question**
>
> Are the bounds on the independence gap different as a function the number of variables $n \geq 2$?

Comment: Maybe the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality) inequality can be leveraged somehow?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) \geq n \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k}^n P(A_k)}$$

Comment: We also know the that sum of the probabilities can be no more than $n$ and less than zero.

$$n \geq \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) \geq 0$$

Comment: And we know that the product of the marginals is still between zero and one.

$$1 \geq \prod_{k}^kP(A_k) \geq 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not just a question about cumulative distribution functions but about events.

What is the possible range of the difference

$$P\left(A_1 \text{ and } A_2\right) - P\left(A_1\right)P\left(A_2\right) $$

or more generally for $n$ events

$$P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i\right) - \prod_{i =1}^n P\left(A_i\right)$$

---

We can write the individual events as

$$P\left(A_i\right) = P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i\right) + P\left(A_i \text{ and } \bigvee_{i=1}^n \lnot A_i\right)$$

that is, the probability of all $A_i$ plus the probability of $A_i$ when one or more of the other $A_i$ are not the case.

- The lowest minimum occurs when $P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 0$ and $P\left(A_i \text{ and } \bigvee_{i=1}^n \lnot A_i\right) = 1-\frac{1}{n}$. This is when there is always exactly one of the events $A_i$ not true, which needs to occur with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ if we share the probabilities equally (which leads to the largest product). Then

  $$\text{minimum bound} = -\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$
- The largest maximum occur when the events are fully dependent and for all $i$ we have $P\left(A_i\right) = P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i\right)$ which leads to the gap being equal to

  $$\text{fully correlated gap} = P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i \right) - P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^n$$

  which has a maximum in $P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i\right))= (\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$ and

  $$\text{maximum bound} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}} - \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{n-1}} $$

Among with these equations I have the image from this question in my mind [Multiply, add, or condition on probability?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593683/)

[image: explanation sum and product rule]

Also this question: [If 'B is more likely given A', then 'A is more likely given B'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402935/) has that image.

Comment: Are there some typos above where $\bigvee$ should be $\bigwedge$?

Comment: @Galen, that's right I had switched 'and' and 'or'.

Comment: FWIIW I like the hand-drawn diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

For a given $n$, a naive guess is there are optimal $p$ and $q$ such the bounds of the independence gap are given by:

$$\phi \in \left[-q^n, p-p^n \right]$$

where $q \leq \frac{n-1}{n}$.

Let's visualize some cases with Desmos. Here I have separate plots for the lower and upper bounds, but don't be confused by the fact that Desmos is using a generic $x$ in both cases.

[image]

For n=2 we seem to get that $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$. For $q$ this is read off the graph where the purple curve intersects with the the red region and that the purple curve is at its minimum. As far as I have seen, this can be simplified to where $q = \frac{n-1}{n}$, which for $n=2$ gives $q = \frac{1}{2}$. The value of $p$ is whatever the maximum value of the black curve is.

[image]

For $n=3$ we get different answers for $p$ and $q$. It appears that $p \approx 0.5775$, whereas $q = \frac{2}{3}$.

[image]

Changing the $n$ slider in Desmos gives me an impression that the curves converge to a result as $n$ becomes large:

[image]

It also seemed that among the plots that there was always a unique maximum for $p$, and likewise for $q=\frac{n-1}{n}$.For $p-p^n$ the optimal value of $p$ can be specified by its derivative.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \left[ p-p^n \right] = 1 - n p^{n-1}.$$

Letting $\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \left[ p-p^n \right] = 0$, then

$$1 - n p^{n-1} = 0 \iff \sqrt[n-1]{\frac{1}{n}} = p \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt[n-1]{n}} = p$$

We know by the fundamental theorem of algebra that there could be $n-1$ candidates for $p$, but looking at the plots I think $p \in [0,1]$ will imply a unique real-valued solution.

So my revision of the interval is given by:

$$\phi \in \left[ - \left(1\ -\ \frac{1}{n}\right)^n, \left(1\ -\ \frac{1}{n}\right) n^{\left(\frac{1}{1-n}\right)} \right]$$

Plotting the lower and upper bound we can see that near-absolute-unity independence gaps are not achieved even with 14 variables.

[image]

Lastly, we can use these derived bounds to normalize any observed Frechet bounds such that $-1 \leq \phi \leq 1$ as I had originally expected:

$$\phi_{\text{Normalized}} \in \left[ \frac{\max \left(0, \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) - (n-1) \right) - \prod_{k=1}^n P(A_k) }{\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}, \frac{\min_k \{ P(A_k) \} - \prod_{k=1}^n P(A_k)}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)n^{\frac{1}{1-n}}} \right]$$

All of these results are provisional on my guess being correct, which it readily may not be.

Comment: I believe that these thoughts are correct. I have more or less copied them in my answer, but I thought it was ok by adding the idea of using $$P(A_i) = P(\bigvee_{i=1}^n A_i) + P(A_i \text{ and } \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \lnot A_i)$$ and the limits on the latter term.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746610/230586

Answer (score 0):

A quick Monte Carlo suggests that the bounds can be wider for $n> 2$.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2018)

m = 10**6

L = []
U = []

for n in range(2, 101):
    p = np.random.uniform(size=m*n).reshape(m,n)
    sump = np.sum(p, axis=1)
    prodp = np.prod(p, axis=1)

    lower = np.maximum(sump - (n-1), 0) - prodp
    upper = np.min(p, axis=1) - prodp

    L.append(np.min(lower))
    U.append(np.max(upper))
    print(n)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(2,101), L, label='Min Lower Bound')
plt.plot(range(2,101), U, label='Max Upper Bound')
plt.xlabel('Sample Size')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Gap')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The result was:

[image]

which indicates that the interval on the independence gap for greater than 2 variables can be wider than that for two.

Somewhere between $n=7$ and $n=9$ the behaviour in my simulation changes. I suspect this likely showing the $m=10^6$ as a sample size becomes insufficient. Essentially we are sampling uniformly from the interior of an unit $n$-cube, which becomes inefficient for larger dimension than about $n=7$.

An exact expression for the bounds as a function of $n$ would still be appreciated.

Comment: Conjectures: $$\limsup \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 1$$

$$\liminf \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = -1$$

Comment: For `n=3` I noticed that `p[np.argmin(lower)], p[np.argmax(upper)]` gives `(array([0.67840591, 0.65334652, 0.66812344]), array([0.5807617 , 0.58092012, 0.58193792]))`. It was also the case for $n=2$ that the min/max args were for all the probabilities to be equally $\frac{1}{2}$. It leads me to speculate the optima occur when $p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_{n-1} = p_{n-2}$. The min and max may not in general be achieved for the same $p$. So some $p^n$ seems to be important rather than arbitrary probabilities.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746610/230586