# Can we obtain a probability interpretation on these bounds obtained from the ADG and Frechet inequalities?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, interpretation, probability-inequalities

## Background

The **almost-disjoint gap** (ADG) is given by

$$\mathcal{D}_{\mu} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right) \triangleq \mu \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} E_k \right) - \sum_{k=1}^n \mu \left( E_k \right)$$

where $\mu$ is a measure and $\{ E_k \}_{k=1}^n$ are elements of a suitable $\sigma$-algebra. When the ADG equals zero we know that the events are [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) [pairwise disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).

The [IE principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (for probabilities, just to skip general measure) states that

$$P\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k \right) = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n P(E_k)}_{\text{Marginal Terms}} +  \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^n \left((-1)^{k-1} \sum_{\substack{I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n \} \\ |I| = k}} P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} E_i \right) \right)}_{\text{Joint Terms}}$$

where I have labelled what I call the *marginal terms* and *joint terms* in under braces. This tells us directly what the meaning of the ADG is: the joint terms.

$$\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right) = \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^n \left((-1)^{k-1} \sum_{\substack{I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n \} \\ |I| = k}} P\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} E_i \right) \right)}_{\text{Joint Terms}}$$

The Frechet bounds for the probability of a union given the marginal probabilities is given by

$$\max \{ P(E_k) \} \leq P\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} E_k \right) \leq \min \left(1, \sum_{k=1}^n P(E_k) \right).$$

The ADG and Frechet bound together can be used to create bounds on the ADG when the marginal probabilities are given.

$$\max \{ P(E_k) \} - \sum_{k=1}^n P \left( E_k \right) \leq \mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right) \leq \min \left(1, \sum_{k=1}^n P(E_k) \right) - \sum_{k=1}^n P \left( E_k \right)$$

Even not knowing the marginal probabilities we know the most extreme bounds for the ADG can be written in terms of the number of events.

$$1 - n \leq \mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right) \leq 0$$

## The Duck

From here is where I start making some choices to [make a duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test), but I don't know if what I made is actually the duck. What I want is a probability interpretation of a score on $[0,1]$ obtainable from above which says something about the amount of space or events participating in the joint terms.

Noting that $1-n \leq 0$, we can flip the bounds by multiplying by negative one:

$$0 \leq -\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right) \leq n-1.$$

And since $n-1$ will sometimes be greater than 1 we can divide through by $n-1$ to normalize:

$$0 \leq \frac{-\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right)}{n-1} \leq 1$$

Assuming I have not messed up some elementary math, which is always possible, it appears that I have a number that superficially looks like a probability.

One interpretation I am hopeful to obtain is something like $\frac{-\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right)}{n-1}$ being the probability of at least some overlap (i.e. intersection) among the $n$ events. If that interpretation holds, then the complement $1 + \frac{\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right)}{n-1}$ would be the probability of there being no overlap among the events. Both of these interpretations would be up to a set of measure zero, mind you.

## Question

- Is $\frac{-\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right)}{n-1}$ actually a probability?
- If yes, what is its outcome space? I.e. what sort of events does it report probabilities on?
- It would be a delight for me if it were something like the probability of two or more events intersecting.

Comment: While $$\frac{-\mathcal{D}_{P} \left( E_1, \ldots, E_n \right)}{n-1}$$ has an indeterminate form for the upper bound when considering $n=1$, I think we can [morally](https://eugeniacheng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cheng-morality.pdf) define it to be zero, thus squeezing the bounded quantity to zero.

Comment: The ADG is analogical to the [independence gap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/589235/69508) which also [has bounds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622994/69508) based on Frechet inequalties.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748115/is-the-almost-disjoint-gap-minimized-when-all-the-sets-almost-overlap