# Correlation among 10 binary variables

Tags: r, binary-data

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

All these social determinants are binary variable. How can I find the correlation among them? By chisq.test? Since I have 11 variables and it will be 55 pairs. Is there any convenient way to do so?

R code, function, logic

Comment: Correlation is defined for continuous variables, not binary variables. What is your research question? Food score does not look binary.

Comment: Maybe start with contingency tables?

Comment: Perhaps an interesting read for you "BayesBinMix: an R Package for Model Based Clustering of Multivariate Binary
Data" https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-022/RJ-2017-022.pdf

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Correlations isn't it, but I don't know what is. Explain it to us in substantive terms.

Comment: You can feed your binary matrix with $k$ columns to `cor` and get a $k\times k$ correlation matrix out, `MM <- matrix(runif(10*100)<0.3,ncol=10)+0; cor(MM)`. Of course correlations are defined for binary variables - they are just probably useless. So I agree with the other commenters that it might be best if you told us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You might look into correspondence analysis, search this site!

Comment: @user2974951 While I don't recommend Pearson's correlation for binary variables b/c there are often better alternatives, correlation *is defined* for binary variables. Consider its construction through substituting the [mean, variance, and covariance of an indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Mean,_variance_and_covariance).

Comment: The covariance of an indicator function is an [independence gap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association/589235#589235) which [has Frechet bounds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622994/69508).

Answer (score 0):

If your question can be understood has "how to apply a comparison function to every pair of columns in a data.frame" then I would suggest the following:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- replicate(5, sample(0:1, 10, T)) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("skip.med", "stable.housing", "utility.bills", "legal.issues", "addiction"))

comps <- combn(colnames(df),2) |>
  as.data.frame()
colnames(comps) <- sapply(comps, \(x) paste(x[[1]],"-",x[[2]]))

lapply(comps,\(x) {
  chisq.test(df[[x[[1]]]], df[[x[[2]]]])
})
```

As suggested in the comments to your question, `chisq.test` may not be the best option, but you can easily change the function used within the `lapply` call.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going back to basics and using a measure that is tailored to binary responses.  If two binary responses $A, B$ are independent then $\Pr(A=a, B=b) = \Pr(A=a)\times \Pr(B=b)$.  You can use $\Pr(A=1,B=1) - \Pr(A=1)\times\Pr(B=1)$ as a measure of dependence of $A$ and $B$.  This is estimated by computing the average product of the binary responses minus the product of the averages.  This is like the numerator of a Pearson correlation coefficient.

This is implemented in the R `Hmisc` package [`varclus function`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/5.1-0/topics/varclus) - see `similarity='bothpos'` or `'ccbothpos`, the latter being what I described above.  You can print the similarity matrix and `varclus` uses it to cluster the variables.