# Deriving Bayes Rule from conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional

Bayes Rule and Conditional Probability look so similar to me.
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to derive Bayes from the conditional probability equation.
If I start with $$P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$$, how do I get to
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

Comment: Use conditional probability twice to write P(A,B) as equal to two different things.

Comment: (I didn't post an explicit solution due to the impression that this was very likely a self-study question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decomposing the joint probability both ways, you get:

$$\mathbb{P}(A,B) = \mathbb{P}(B|A) \mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A|B) \mathbb{P}(B).$$

Consequently, you get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(A|B)
= \frac{\mathbb{P}(A,B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} 
= \frac{\mathbb{P}(B|A) \mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}.
\end{align}$$

For more information on the intuition of this result, and a way of expressing it via a symmetry principle, see [this related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179587/388488#388488).