# Is it silly to use describe an event as "Bayesian" when not dealing with statistic per se?

Tags: bayesian

For example, say it is rare that your roommate eats cereal, however, one day you see an empty bowl with milk stain and later in the day you saw some cereal crumbs. You now conclude that most likely your roommate ate cereal.  But the question is can you now say well its "bayesian-like" given the new observations?

Comment: It is unclear what the example has to do with Bayesian inference, let alone what is meant with 'to describe an event as Bayesian'.

Comment: H_0 = no cereal was eaten. Data = bowl with stains, plus crumbs. 
p(D|H_0) = low. This is frequentist thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in a private conversation you can say many things. What harm does it do?

However, personally I wouldn't call this Bayesian, because no computations and no quantities are involved, and people have made conclusions like this without knowing anything of Bayes, and quite certainly already before Bayes's time.

Making reference to the headline, in any case it's not the *event* that could be Bayesian, but rather your reasoning about it.

Answer (score 3):

Whether this inference is Bayesian-like depends far too much on the unspecified meaning of "like". Silly or not, this aspect of the question is unanswerable in this format.

Bayesian inference is not synonymous with any use of previously-existing beliefs while evaluating evidence. [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) is a form of probabilistic inference that requires specifying probability distributions, including a [prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability), which is absent from this inference about eating cereal.

As for an event itself being Bayesian, I agree with [Christian Hennig's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594943/is-it-silly-to-use-describe-an-event-as-bayesian-when-not-dealing-with-statist/594949#594949):

> Making reference to the headline, in any case it's not the event that could be Bayesian, but rather your reasoning about it.

Comment: The prior here is that the roommate rarely eats cereal. Is the argument that "rarely" needs to be numerically defined in order to be a prior?

Comment: "The roommate rarely eats cereal" is a not a prior probability distribution, which is required for Bayesian inference. Whether that is "like a prior" depends on what one chooses to mean by "like".

Answer (score 2):

An event itself is neither Bayesian nor non-Bayesian; it is just an event.  The *method of inference* you use to come to your conclusion may or may not be Bayesian, depending on how you did your reasoning.  Bayesian inference operates by *incorporating prior information* into the inference using Bayes rule (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388488#388488) for an intuited view of what this means).  As you can see from the linked post, Bayesian inference can be captured in a symmetry principle.  Suppose we start from a state where we have no knowledge about the occurrence or non-occurrence of an event, and the truth or falsity of a hypothesis.  If we consider that the occurrence of the event makes the hypothesis $x$% more (less) likely and likewise the truth of the hypothesis makes the event $x$% more (less) likely, and if we make our inference consistently on that basis (i.e., applying the rules of probability in a way that is consistent with that symmetry) then that is Bayesian reasoning.

In the present case, the prior information is that the roommate rarely eats cereal and the observed evidence is that there is an empty cereal bowl, milk and cereal crumbs in a place where only you and your roommate are expected to be.  Bayesian reasoning would go like this: (a) If my roommate ate cereal today it is $80 \%$ more likely that I would observe that bowl, milk, crumbs, etc. (compared to when this hypothesis is unknown); (b) my roommate rarely eats cereal, so the baseline probability that he ate cereal today is only $5 \%$; (c) Therefore, having observed the evidence, it is $80 \%$ more likely than usual that he ate cereal today, so the posterior probability he ate cereal today is $9 \%$.  If your reasoning was something like that, you could reasonably describe it as Bayesian.